# javascript function output math calculation

Tags: javascript

I am following a javascript video tutorial on pluralsight.com & they have a javascript function but I don't understand how they got this result:

```
function factorial(n){
    if (n === 0 || n === 1){
    return 1;
    }
return n * factorial(n-1);

}
console.log( factorial(5) ); // result is 120
```

Can anyone please explain me why this function is returning 120? I would expect it to return 5 * 4 = 20?
[>> JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/f8xaysqj/)

Comment: Look up what factorial means.

Comment: It returns `5 * factorial(4)`. `factorial(4)` returns `4 * factorial(3)`...

Answer (score 1):

Its a recursive function, it calls itself: `return n * factorial(n-1)`. So `factorial(5)` calls itself with `4` as argument and `factorial(4)` calls itself with `3` as argument and so on.